# how to add "search by usernane or email address" field in django forgot password

Tags: python, django, django-forms, web-frameworks

this is a django default forgot password form. how to modify to add "search by username" feature. for example "username/email". can someone help me with this. i am a noob in django. just started learning.

```
def get_users(self, email):

    active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(**{
        '%s__iexact' % UserModel.get_email_field_name(): email,
        'is_active': True,
    })
    return (u for u in active_users if u.has_usable_password())

def save(self, domain_override=None,
         subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
         use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
         from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
         extra_email_context=None):
    """
    Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and send it to the
    user.
    """
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    for user in self.get_users(email):
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        context = {
            'email': email,
            'domain': domain,
            'site_name': site_name,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'user': user,
            'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
            **(extra_email_context or {}),
        }
        self.send_mail(
            subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email,
            email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can search both on the email field and the `username` field by usign [**`Q` objects** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_users(self, email):
    active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(
        Q(**{'%s__iexact' % UserModel.get_email_field_name(): email}) |
        Q(username=email),
        is_active=True
    )
    return (u for u in active_users if u.has_usable_password())
```

You can add the [**`__iexact`** field lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) to the username, so `username__iexact=email` if you want to search for usernames in a case *in*sensitive manner.

In the `save` function, you probably should use the `email` of the user instead:

```
def save(self, domain_override=None,
         subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
         use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
         from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
         extra_email_context=None):
    """
    Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and send it to the
    user.
    """
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    for user in self.get_users(email):
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        email = getattr(user, UserModel.get_email_field_name())
        context = {
            'email': email,
            'domain': domain,
            'site_name': site_name,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'user': user,
            'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
            **(extra_email_context or {}),
        }
        self.send_mail(
            subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email,
            email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Willem. What about this part.                                               context={'email':email}

Comment: @ashley: normally it will just take the value that was entered in the text box (that has apparently the name `email`, so that should not change).

Comment: See the context part. It it taking email address from userinput in context section